# Laravel Gates and Policies

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

The following Gate definitions are working fine:

```
    Gate::define('create_role','App\Policies\RolePolicy@create_role');

    Gate::define('view_role','App\Policies\RolePolicy@view_role');

    Gate::define('edit_role','App\Policies\RolePolicy@edit_role');

    Gate::define('delete_role','App\Policies\RolePolicy@delete_role');
```

but when I changed it to,

```
    Gate::resource('roles', 'App\Policies\RolePolicy', [
        'create_role' => 'create_role',
        'view_role' => 'view_role',
        'edit_role' => 'edit_role',
        'delete_role' => 'delete_role',
    ]);
```

for reducing LOC and optimizing code. It is not working.

Following are the lines of code in my blade file,

```
                @can('create_role')
                <a href="{{route('create_role')}}">Add Role</a>
                @endcan


                @can('view_role')
                <a href="{{route('view_role')}}"> View Roles</a>                    
                @endcan
```

Similarly for edit and delete.
The behavior observed is as such that it is only receiving false from the policy methods. I even tried out sending only true from it, but makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create extra gates?. Given you passed that extra parameter in the array.
The array after gate definition is used to create extra gate definitions.
For more info go through the docs,
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-gates).
When using resourceful policies.

eg:

```
Gate::resource('roles', 'App\Policies\RolePolicy');

@can('roles.view')
// html here
@endcan

@can('roles.create')
//html here
@endcan
```